# Getting Parseerror from Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've seen this asked before, but the standard solution - remove `dataType: "json"` doesn't work for me.

Here is my PHP (less all the prep steps):

```
if (mail($strTo, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    return '{"message":"email was sent successfully"}';
} else {
    return '{"message":"email was not sent"}';
}
```

Here is my AJAX call in Javascript:

```
var mailData = {'idMatch':'27', 'admin':'True', 'subject':"Score Update", 'message': composeEmail()};
$.ajax({
    url: '/assets/php/send_mail.php', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: mailData, 
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        }
    });
```

It keeps returning as a "parseerror", with the following status:

```
{readyState: 4, responseText: "↵↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

From what I can tell, the code is working. The response should be success. And I'm both sending and receiving in JSON. I'm afraid I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: '{"message":"email was not sent}'; should be '{"message":"email was not sent"}';

Comment: You are correct. That was an edit error when I pasted into SO. It is correct in the actual code. I have corrected it here.